# How to modify the value of a Python variable(like a refrence) in python

Tags: python, c, cpython, python-c-api

I am writing a syscall wrapper for python(just as a fun project to get me used to the API),
 and when I came upon implementing read(), I am perplexed as to how I can modify a python buffer that is sent to my function.

The function is a simple cpython wrapper around the read() syscall.
It takes an integer (the file descriptor), a buffer, and the maximum you want to read, then returns the amount read.

I have everything working except for the modification of the buffer:

```
py_obj py_read(py_obj self, py_obj args){
    char* buff;
    int fd;
    int len;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "isi", &fd, &buff, &len)){
        return NULL;
    }

    return Py_BuildValue("i", read(fd, buff, len));
}
```

After loading the module, then calling read:

```
>> from syscalls import read
>> STDIN = 1
>> s = ""
>> read(STDIN,s, 256)
napkin
7
>> s
""
```

Though this is what I expected (and is what should happen, since I did not have an actual reference to the argument), I would like to know how to get a reference to the parameter.

**EDIT**:
After using @user2357112, it still does not modify the value

```
>>> b = memoryview(b"")
>>> from syscalls import *
>>> read(1, b, 10)
test
5
>>> b
<memory at 0x7fa060628408>
>>> b.tolist()
[]
>>>
```

**EDIT 2**:
But it does work with bytearray, if I size it correctly
Thank you  @user2357112

Comment: This question is way too broad. It isn't clear what you've tried, what your desired outcome is or what the problem is! Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Thank you @Karl for notifying me!  I realize it way too unclear.   Now knowing that I have updated the question and provided examples to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *have* a reference to the argument. You may have just corrupted the argument object or the memory surrounding it, in fact. You don't have a reference to the caller's `s` variable, but variables and references don't work like that in Python anyway; references always refer to objects.

Python string objects aren't appropriate for use as mutable buffers. They're supposed to be immutable, after all. Also, they're Unicode, and `read` reads bytes. Instead, use an appropriately-sized [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) and view its contents through a [`Py_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.Py_buffer) structure with the `y*` format code.

Also, since `read` returns `ssize_t` rather than `int`, you should use the `n` format code rather than `i`. `n` corresponds to `Py_ssize_t`, which is intended to match `ssize_t` when `ssize_t` exists.

```
PyObject *my_read(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    Py_buffer buff;
    int fd;
    int len;

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iy*i", &fd, &buff, &len)){
        return NULL;
    }

    ssize_t read_count = read(fd, buff.buf, len);
    PyBuffer_Release(&buff);

    return Py_BuildValue("n", read_count);
}
```

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy: I could've sworn I had the `.buf`. Fixing...

Comment: Stil not modifying it (Using memoryviewer)

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy: I don't know what you mean by "memoryviewer". Did you size the bytearray appropriately?

Comment: Is there a way to make it so they don't have to initialize the bytearray, for sizeing purposes?

Comment: @Mememyselfandaverycreepy: Yes, but you should consider your design objectives first. If your goal is to have a very direct translation between the Python interface and the C `read` function, then you should require the user to provide an appropriately-sized buffer, just like what the C interface requires. If you want a convenient Python interface, then why have the user provide a buffer at all? You could just make your own bytearray - or you could just use the existing [`os.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.read), or you could just use a file object the usual way.

Comment: I see your point, is that the only way to allocate a buffer in Python?

Comment: You could technically use other objects that expose the buffer interface, but a bytearray is probably the most appropriate.